# Share Code Between Device Projects

Tags: xcode, cordova, intellij-idea

I am using ItelliJ and XCode 4.5 to develop a PhoneGap application.  I would like to share a lot of the resources used between both projects, but haven't found a good solution yet.  I tried symbolic links but that doesn't end up working well.  Is there a way for me to do this without having to make sure I have code in sync between devices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I divide project on several parts:

- "www" project, which contains html/js/css
- android project
- ios project

Android and ios projects repos have "www" project repo as submodule(I use git).
I also create separate folders ios and android in "www" project.

In index.html I analyze user agent string and include appropriate phonegap.js file.
[Example](https://gist.github.com/4283398).